# VBA transpose data

Tags: vba, excel

How do I make the data appear transposed rather than horizontal?

Here is my code. It takes the value from Cell A1 and places only the numeric values into separate cells.

```
Sub match2()
Dim count, count1 As Integer
Dim holder As String
Dim sample, smallSample    As String
count = 0
count1 = 1
sample = Worksheets("Match2").Range("A1").Value
holder = ""
With Sheet4
Do While count <> Len(sample)
    smallSample   = Left(sample, 1)
    If smallSample   = "0" Or smallSample  = "1" Or smallSample  = "2" Or smallSample = "3" Or smallSample = "4" Or smallSample  = "5" Or smallSample  
= "6" Or smallSample  = "7" Or smallSample  = "8" Or smallSample = "9" Then 
    holder = holder & smallSample
    Else
        If holder <> "" Then
          Cells(count1, 1) = holder
            count1 = count1 + 1     
        End If
        holder = ""
    End If
    sample = (Right(sample, Len(sample) - 1))
Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe `Cells(1, count1) = holder`, because it is `Cells(Rows, Columns)`

Comment: Unrelated sidenote, on your dim's you need to specify the variable type for each otherwise they'll default as variant. i.e. `dim count as long, count1 as long`

Comment: Thanks danieltakeshi

Comment: How would I make the code look through all of column A and not just cell A1?

Answer (score 1):

To make it transposed and to whole column A

And the code had an issue, that if it ended with a number, it would end the function without printing the last number. e.g.: inpute: `i1i2` would output just `1`. However, it was fixed with `If Len(sample) = 1 Then Cells(i, count1) = holder`

```
Sub match2()
Dim count As Long, count1 As Long
Dim holder As String
Dim sample As String, smallSample  As String
Dim LastRowa As Long

count = 0
LastRowa = Worksheets("Match2").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
With Sheet4
    For i = 1 To LastRowa
    count1 = 1
    holder = ""
    sample = Worksheets("Match2").Range("A" & i).Value
    Do While count <> Len(sample)
        smallSample = Left(sample, 1)
        If smallSample = "0" Or smallSample = "1" Or smallSample = "2" Or smallSample = "3" Or smallSample = "4" Or smallSample = "5" Or smallSample = "6" Or smallSample = "7" Or smallSample = "8" Or smallSample = "9" Then
        holder = holder & smallSample
        Else
            If holder <> "" Then
              Cells(i, count1) = holder
              count1 = count1 + 1
            End If
            holder = ""
        End If
        If Len(sample) = 1 Then Cells(i, count1) = holder
        sample = (Right(sample, Len(sample) - 1))
    Loop
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```